# jQuery Mobile form Validation and html 5

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm new to the whole jQuery Mobile and HTML5 space (so bear with me) and I am validating forms for the first time. Now I would really like to validate the forms using html 5 where the following pops up:

[image]

Now I've decided to give this a bash and have the following code:

```
<form>
     <input required type="text" name="searchtitle" id="searchtitle" placeholder="Enter the textbook's title">
     <input type="submit" id ="searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" value="Search">
 </form>
```

Now I have the following code for when the 'Search' button above is clicked:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',"#searchpage",
function()
{
   $("#searchsubmit").click(
   function(e)
   {
   //Do a lot of processing here
   window.location.href ="#results";
   }  
 });
```

Now I'm note sure why when I click the Search button click event is run and not stopped because of the form validation and if I am completely wrong can someone point me in the right direction that will teach me how to do the form validation using the HTML5

Answer (score 3):

Those HTML5 "popups" you mentioned are implemented by the browsers themselves.

I don't think there is great support for them. Particularly on mobile browsers, which is where you would typically run a jQuery Mobile app.

I would use something like jQuery Validate to handle the form validation for now if I were you.

http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: Well I'm making the jQuery Mobile App for phonegap so will the banners mentioned in my question still work there? Also is there any other way of doing the form validation other than in the link you provided? I really want it to be like the banners in my question, any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1638809 - will popup error messages appear with jQuery Validate? Yes, but by default they will have their own styling. You could style it to look the same as the html5 one - but that will be up to you to do with CSS.

There are many ways to validate html forms. jQuery Validate is a popular Javascript validation library, that is a good choice for a lot of projects. If it doesn't work well for you (it should) then try searching for some other Javascript validation libs. I'm just saying that it's probably better to go down that path, than use the poorly supported html5 browser validation

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not stopped is because an `input type="submit"` will submit by default, so it's reloading the page. You need to add the following line to your code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',"#searchpage",
function()
{
   $("#searchsubmit").click(
   function(e)
   {
   e.preventDefault(); // add this line to prevent the form from submitting regardless.
   //Do a lot of processing here
   window.location.href ="#results";
   }  
 });
```

Comment: just added the e.preventdefault() line and still getting the same problem

Comment: can I ask you why you are redirecting to : #results?

Comment: With in the #searchsubmit function I do a lot of dynamically adding to  elements in the results page and hence the redirect

Comment: on mobile I would recommend to go with what asgeo1 posted. The support would be better and you don't have to do redirects which will be messy.